# Como passar objetos de métodos que estão em controllers diferentes no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, método, objetos, controller

Boa noite.

O que eu preciso é exibir o nome do livro onde está o seu id (na coluna Livro do form).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
E para que eu não faça de uma maneira fora da convenção, gostaria de saber a maneira correta de fazer isso.

Tenho o método *painel* que está no controller *HomeController* que passa para minha view os objetos abaixo para formar a table:

```
    public function painel(){
        $livro = Livro::all();
        $lote = Lote::all();
        $status = Status::all();
        return view('painel.index', compact('livro', 'lote', 'status'));
        
    }
```

E também tenho o controller *LoteController* onde de lá eu precisaria passar pra essa mesma view *'painel.index'* o nome do livro (livro->titulo) e não o id do livro que está na tabela de Lote (lote->livro_id).

Gostaria de saber qual a maneira correta para fazer tal procedimento. Se caso eu estiver errado na forma que estou fazendo, estou livre para aceitar as críticas para assim melhorar o meu código. Obrigado!

View painel.index:

```
div class="container">
    <h1>Consulta de Lotes</h1>
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Lote</th>
                <th>Livro</th>
                <th>Data Início</th>
                <th>Data de Encerramento</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            

            @foreach ($lote as $lotes)
                <tr>
                    <th>{{ $lotes->id }}</th>
                    <th>{{ $lotes->livro_id }}</th>
                    <th>{{ $lotes->dia_inicio }}</th>
                    <th>{{ $lotes->dia_fim }}</th>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se na sua migration de livros você criou o livro_id como chave estrangeira referenciando a tabela livros, basta vc criar o relacionamento no modelo lote e usar o relacionamento em qualquer lugar do sistema que vc precisar.

Na migration da tabela de lotes:

```
$table->unisignedInteger('livro_id');
$table->foregin('livro_id')->references('id')->on('livros')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Checa de o seu ID de livros foi criado com Integer ou BigInteger, a chave estrangeira tem que ser do mesmo tipo só que unsigned

No modelo de Lotes

```
public function livro() {
   return $this->hasOne(Livro::class);
}
```

Depois, no controller que vc precisar vc faz a consulta:

```
$lotes = Lotes::with(['livro'])->get(); // o with aqui é opcional, vai evitar que na view o laravel faça outra consulta no banco
return view('painel.index', ['lotes' => $lotes]);
```

Na view

```
@foreach ($lotes as $lote)
<tr>
   <td>{{ $lote->id }}</td>
   <td>{{ $lote->livro->titulo }}</td> // se este for o compo da tabela livros que vc quer
   <td>{{ $lotes->dia_inicio }}</td>
   <td>{{ $lotes->dia_fim }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Eu escrevi o código aqui e agora, pode ter algum errinho, mas, a ideia é essa...

Você ainda pode no modelo de livros ter um método que retorna todos os lotes usando hasMany (acho que é isso)

Answer (score -1):

Pode fazer um join na consulta, exemplo:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('contacts', 'users.id', '=', 'contacts.user_id')
            ->join('orders', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->select('users.*', 'contacts.phone', 'orders.price')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Valeu amigo. Eu fiz dessa forma aí mesmo enquanto aguardava as respostas. Mas de qualquer forma eu preciso separar cada coisa em seu model (classe), para deixar coerente.